# Show reduction end date prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would to create a countdown system for a product reduction in prestashop. So I need to show the reduction end date.
I modified product.tpl with these lines :

```
 {if ($product->reduction_to)}
    <p id="reduc">{$product->reduction_to|date_format:'%d %B %Y'} </p>
{/if}
```

But nothing's happened. The product page isn't modified. Is there an error in my code?

I'm using a fresh install of the last version of prestashop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{$product->specificPrice.to|date_format:'%d %B %Y'}`

Comment: Right, thanks. I found `$product->reduction_to` in the docs. Strange. Thank you!